# Executing application when Android is about to lock the screen / go sleep

Tags: android

I would like my application to react to screen locking / putting phone into sleep. Based on some condition my application could decide to allow locking/sleep or to do something.

I want to use it that way:

1. User install my application (he don't have to run it all the time).
2. When phone want to go sleep or the screen is about to lock, my application receive the "message".
3. My application run some logic and decided either to allow lock/sleep or to perform some operation (that will prevent screen from lock this time).

If the user turn off the phone, my application can but don't have to react to it.

**Is it possible to receive and react to screen locking and/or start of the sleep in order to prevent it (sometimes)?**

Comment: Why on earth would you ever want to do THAT? Sounds incredibly sinister! If however you're not attempting to be REALLY dodgy, you could look at this: https://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/24/handling-screen-off-and-screen-on-intents/ - May get you on the right path.

Comment: @LokiSinclair Thx for the link to the article :) I want to do so because I am witting the application for businessman who wants to display his "logo" on the phone for 10 minutes before locking the screen (e.g. he goes to restaurant, send an sms, put the phone on the table and people around see the image on his phone for about 10 minutes before the phone goes asleep). It's an order and not my idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you can first let your app receive the `ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` intent, which would do:

> When phone want to go sleep or the screen is about to lock, my application receive the "message".

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SCREEN_OFF

You can also use the `PowerManager` to wake the device up too, which

> will prevent screen from lock this time

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html